# iOS how to add custom code to a class method without subclassing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, polymorphism, nsurlcache

If I use a core iOS class in my app, like NSURLCache; I would like to print a log message anytime `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses]` gets called. **How can I extend a class method like that without explicitly subclassing NSURLCache and replacing all references of that within a project with a custom class?** Is there some way to do this with  category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [Method Swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/MethodSwizzling). Here is [a page with a nice overview of the technique](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) from which I borrowed most of the code below:

```
@interface SwizzleNSURLCache : NSURLCache
+(void)load;
-(void)swzl_removeAllCachedResponses;
@end

+(void)load {
    Class class = [SwizzleNSURLCache class];
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(removeAllCachedResponses);
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swzl_removeAllCachedResponses);

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

    BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class,
        originalSelector,
        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod(class,
            swizzledSelector,
            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}

-(void) swzl_removeAllCachedResponses {
    // This is your replacement method. You can do whatever you want here.
    NSLog(@"Running removeAllCachedResponses");
    // If you need to call the actual implementation, do it like this:
    [self swzl_removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

You do not need to replace references of `NSURLCache` with this subclass. All you need is to load it once from some place in your program.

Note: I am not sure if there is an easier way to do it. Method swizzling is definitely a heavy artillery, but it gets the job done.